# How to stub external interface in JEE6 application for testing?

Tags: jakarta-ee, testing, mocking

I need to stub an external interface for testing in a JEE6 application.
From the research I have done, it seems that there are 3 options

1. Use an alternative
2. Use @Specializes annotation
3. Use Mockito

Which option is best to use?

Comment: Is this a unit test, integration test or what?

Comment: It would be an integration test so I don't want to test the external API right?I should stub that out as we don't develop and there is unit tests covering the behaviour of that API. I know this question is kind of subjective but I'm looking for what's best practice. Mockito to me seems the best choice as it's simpler,I don't have to change deployment setup in arquillian by deploying a different beans.xml or add in the @Specializes bean

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing unit-testing the first thing you should try is to use fakes. Just extract the interface from your UI and implement it as a fake.
Example:

```
interface MyUI {
    void displayText(String text);
}
```

You would build the fake:

```
class FakeUI implements MyUI {
    @Override
    void displayText(String text) {
        myFieldVariable = text;
    }
}
```

The last one would be an inner class of your test which could do something like:

```
@Test
public itShouldDisplayHello() {
    myBean.print("hello")
    assertEquals("hello", myFieldVariable);
}
```

That's it, you don't even have a need for mocks, plain old java.